# Can we have same abstract method in parent and child class

Tags: oop, inheritance, abstract

I have got one question.

I two abstract classes A and B.B is inheriting A so now can we have same abstract method which there in class A in class B without implementation(no override).

Conditions:

1.It should have same same and signature in both abstract class
2.We will inherit B to class C and implement it in the class C.
3.no method hiding

Regards
Krishna

```cs
public abstract class A
{
  public void info();
}

public abstract class B:A 
{
  public void info();
}

public abstract class C:B
{
  public void info()
  {
    // code
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @DorShinar the post title is the question

Answer (score 1):

assuming your question is in c# code then following is possible:-

```
public abstract class A
{
  public abstract void info();
}

public abstract class B:A 
{
  public override abstract void info();
}

public abstract class C:B
{
  public override void info()
  {
    // code
  }
}
```

but if you remove the `override` keyword from `info` in class B, its a compile time error.

Also you can simply not define the method at all in B and override it in C because C's parent is B and B's parent is A so C automatically has access to everything in A unless its private